# Can there be nonisomorphic pullbacks corresponding to different induced isomorphisms?

Tags: category-theory, pullback

In Vistoli's FGA explained, when he introduces fibered categories he defines Cartesian arrows and pullbacks.  The definition of Cartesian arrow makes sense and is standard, and then he defines pullback:

> If $\xi\rightarrow\eta$ is a Cartesian arrow of $F$ mapping to an arrow $U\rightarrow V$ of $C$, we also say  that $\xi$ is a pullback of $\eta$ to $U$.

He goes on to remark that, given two pullbacks $\phi:\xi\rightarrow\eta$ and $\phi':\xi'\rightarrow\eta$ of $\eta$ to $U$, then $\xi$ and $\xi'$ are uniquely isomorphic.

This gives me pause because I feel that if $\phi$ and $\phi'$ induce different morphisms $U\rightarrow V$, then I don't see why this should be true.  Indeed, looking back at the definition of pullback, it seems essential that the data of the specific arrow $U\rightarrow V$ needs to be specified in order to make a statement like "the pullback is unique up to unique isomorphism."  This is needed for other examples of pullbacks in math anyway.  So I just want confirmation that indeed this is the case, because the text of the definition is at best unclear to me.

Comment: Yes, the morphism in the base is fixed in this discussion.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought.